# Convert mat-select to mat-autocomplete using Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Im trying to add auto-complete to a mat-form field. When I add the  brackets I get an error. Here is the code:

```
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Dropdown</mat-label>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onDropdownChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" [(ngModel)]="someValue">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let someValue of someValues" [value]="someValue.id">
     {{otherValue.otherValues}}
     </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You mentioned that there is an error. Please edit your question to include the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular material already has an autocomplete component, you need to use it instead:
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

[stackblitz](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts)